# Configure kairosdb with graphite

Tags: graphite, kairosdb

The graphite document says we can use the kairosdb for storing metrics but I could not find a clear guide on how to configure graphite to pull data from kairosdb. I chose kairos DB because it supports REST API to publish data. Could someone help by pointing to any resource which talks about configuring graphite to use kairosdb? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it figured it out. To plug a different datasource other than Whisper, we need a finder plugin as documented [here](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage-backends.html) and the Kairosdb plugin is [here](https://github.com/raintank/graphite-kairosdb).